# Back and Rollback Script for a File Transfer

Tags: powershell, backup, file-transfer

I looking for a good solution to backup and rollback a folder using the Windows(XP/Vista/7) OS.

As an example, say, I have a folder, called "\SOMEOTHERPC\Destination" (that contains files and subfolders). I wish to take a back up of this folder to my local disk. Then, say I was to edit or delete some of the content of this "\SOMEOTHERPC\Destination" folder and the afterwards rollback the folder to its previous state.

What's the best way to go about this. I am thinking of writing a PowerShell script? Perhaps there is a better way. Any suggestions appreciated?

Thanks.

Comment: RoboCopy seems to do the trick requiring just a couple of lines of script. Thanks, f.

Comment: You should add that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RoboCopy seems to do the trick requiring just a couple of lines of script.